# Bolzano-Weierstrass theorems question

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Prove following theorem.

Theorem : If $x$ is a sequence of real numbers that is both bounded and monotone, then $x$ converges.

I know that $x$ is a sequence of real numbers that is both bounded and monotone, this mean $x$ is both bounded above and bounded below, and $x$ can be either "never increasing" or "never decreasing" in order to be monotone. But I don't know how to used these to show that $x$ converges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that the sequence is non-decreasing: $x_n\le x_{n+1}$ for all $n$. Let $X=\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$; $X$ is bounded (why?), so it has a least upper bound $\alpha$. Prove that the sequence $x$ converges to $\alpha$. Then modify this argument to handle the case in which $x$ is non-increasing.